# Power BI - How to limit data imported using date

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

Newbie here. How do I limit the amount of data imported to Power BI? For example, I have a total row count of 1,156,135, but i only want to load the last 90 days is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What kind of source do you have

Answer (score 0):

With Power BI, you can edit the query to pre-filter the data.

On the ribbon, [click Transform Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3b1G.png) to open the Power Query Editor.  The Power Query Editor will show you a sample of the data (not all of it).  Then either you can set up your filters and Power BI will build the query for you, or you can use the [Advanced Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkOXG.png) to write/edit your own query.

Click "Close & Apply" to close the Power Query Editor and load the data.